# False positive in Android lint check for LinkedHashMap.remove()

Tags: java, android, kotlin, lint, android-lint

The issue in the lint result html
[image]

Generated html section by lint for the issue

```
<div class="warningslist">
    <span class="location">
    <a href="../../src/main/java/com/tourlandish/chronos/base/InMemoryCache.kt">../../src/main/java/com/tourlandish/chronos/base/InMemoryCache.kt</a>:40</span>
: <span class="message">Call requires API level 24 (current min is 21): 
<code>java.util.LinkedHashMap#remove</code></span><br /><pre class="errorlines">

    <span class="lineno"> 37 </span>        override <span 
    class="keyword">fun</span> get(key: String): CachedItem? {
    <span class="lineno"> 38 </span>            <span 
    class="keyword">val</span> value = <span 
    class="keyword">super</span>.get(key) ?: <span 
    class="keyword">return</span> <span class="keyword">null</span>
    <span class="lineno"> 39 </span>            <span 
    class="keyword">if</span> (value.isExpired()) {
    <span class="caretline"><span class="lineno"> 40 </span>                
    <span class="error">remove</span>(key)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
    <span class="lineno"> 41 </span>                <span 
    class="keyword">return</span> <span class="keyword">null</span>
    <span class="lineno"> 42 </span>            }
    <span class="lineno"> 43 </span>            <span 
    class="keyword">return</span> value
    </pre>

</div>
```

But `LinkedHashMap.remove()` which inherits from `HashMap.remove()` was added in API level 1 [according to the Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html#remove(java.lang.Object))

Is there some extra configuration needed for android-lint to work along with kotlin or is it a bug in android-lint and we have to supress it until fixed?

Comment: And what exactly is the question? If somebody is willing to write up a bug report?

Comment: @GhostCat Sorry. Added the question apart from the bug report. Thanks.

Comment: Please report the issue at http://kotl.in/issue

Comment: @KirillRakhman Reported here - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-18218. Thanks